# understanding Hecke characters

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, hecke-characters

How do I understand Hecke characters? For example, is there a bijection between Hecke characters and something? For example, if a Hecke character factors through a ray class group, by Artin reciprocity, we would have a 1-1 correspondence with characters of finite abelian Galois groups with restricted ramification.

I'm aware of [Understanding Hecke Characters as Extension of Dirichlet Characters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3902471/understanding-hecke-characters-as-extension-of-dirichlet-characters), but this does not answer my question. [Motivation for Hecke characters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11679/motivation-for-hecke-characters) is a bit more helpful. For example, what is the interpretation of infinity types?

Comment: To answer your first question, class field theory gives a bijection between Hecke characters over $K$ (i.e. characters of $\mathbb A_K^\times/K^\times$) and one dimensional $\ell$-adic Galois representations $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline K/K)\to \overline{\mathbb Q}_\ell^\times$. The infinity type gets encoded in a slightly complicated way as whats going on at $G_K$ restricted to the decomposition group at primes above $\ell$. So you do get a correspondence with characters of Galois groups of abelian, but not necessarily finite, extensions. Is that the type of thing you're looking for?

Comment: @Mathmo123: Yes, that's in my spirit. Does this hold for all $\ell$ when fixing one Hecke character? I'm asking because the image of the decomposition group at $\ell$ can be infinite, but not that at other primes. So in fact, you get a compatible system of $\ell$-adic Galois representations? Do you have a reference (not too technical, but yet precise) explaining the interpretation of the infinity types?

Comment: My previous comment was slightly imprecise. The correspondence with $\ell$-adic representations only holds for *algebraic* Hecke characters: namely, characters whose infinity types are suitably integral. In that case, you do get a compatible system. Take a look at [these notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/modseminar/pdf/L11.pdf) for more detail.

Comment: Essentially, the point is that, by class field theory, there is a natural isomorphism $K^\times\backslash\mathbb A_K^\times/\overline{(K_\infty^\times)^0}\cong G_K^{ab}$. So as long as the infinity type (encoded in $K_\infty^\times$) plays nice, there is a tight connection between Hecke characters and Galois characters.

Comment: @Mathmo123: Thanks, that and this note sheds much more light on my question.